# Print a map with Geotools

Tags: java, geotools, printing, rendering

I want to print a map with a raster image as base-map using Geotools.
The problem is that the raster image doesn't take the margins into consideration and starts always at the point (0,0) as you can see in the image below

[image: My map Pdf]

My code :

```
protected void RasterConnect() {
         List<Parameter<?>> list = new ArrayList<Parameter<?>>();
         list.add(new Parameter<File>("image", File.class, "Image",
                       "GeoTiff or World+Image to display as basemap", new KVP(
                                    Parameter.EXT, "tif", Parameter.EXT, "jpg")));

         JParameterListWizard wizard = new JParameterListWizard("Image Lab",
                       "Fill in the following layers", list);
         int finish = wizard.showModalDialog();

         if (finish != JWizard.FINISH) {
                System.exit(0);
         }
         File rasterFile = (File) wizard.getConnectionParameters().get("image");


         AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(rasterFile);
         reader = format.getReader(rasterFile);

         // Initially display the raster in greyscale using the
         // data from the first image band
         Style rasterStyle = createGreyscaleStyle(1);

         Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(reader, rasterStyle);
         map.addLayer(rasterLayer);
   }

public void pdf(Object object) throws FileNotFoundException,
                DocumentException {

         int marge = Mediator.getMarge();
         int scale = Mediator.getScale();
         float widthA4 = Mediator.getSize().getWidth();
         float heightA4 = Mediator.getSize().getHeight();
         float heightA4MeterWithoutMargin = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities
                       .pointsToMillimeters(heightA4 - marge * 2) / 1000;

         Document doc = new Document(Mediator.getSize().rotate(), 10f, 10f,
                       100f, 0f);

         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(
                       "d:\\test4.pdf"));
         doc.open();
         PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
         Graphics2D graphics = cb.createGraphics(heightA4, widthA4);
         GTRenderer draw = new StreamingRenderer();
         Rectangle outputArea = new Rectangle(marge, marge,
                       (int) (heightA4 - marge * 2), (int) (widthA4 - marge * 2));

         ReferencedEnvelope referencedEnvelope=referencedEnvelopeToScale(scale,marge, widthA4,heightA4,heightA4MeterWithoutMargin);
         map.getViewport().setBounds(referencedEnvelope);



         draw.setMapContent(map);

       draw.paint(graphics, outputArea, referencedEnvelope);


         // Grid
         com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle rect = createRectangleBorder(marge,
                       outputArea);
         cb.rectangle(rect);

         MyFooter event = showInfoPaper(outputArea, scale, "map");
         writer.setPageEvent(event);

         createCrossCoord(marge, scale,  writer, cb,
                       referencedEnvelope);

         cb.fill();

         // cleanup
         graphics.dispose();

         // cleanup
         doc.close();
         writer.close();

   }
```

PS : Vector layers work perfectly, the problem occurs only with raster.

Comment: can you add the code which loads the image? all the printing code looks fine

Comment: Ok thank's, I've added the function that loads the raster file

Comment: what is in referencedEnvelopeToScale(...)?

Comment: it's the function I used to center my map on the paper, I give it the margin to start at (50,50) (in the attached image) rather than 0,0

Comment: @Youssef I am creating print printing service using code almost same as your but my map data get affected by margin i provide and hides the data on right side so i think uisng referencedEnvelopeToScale will resolve this , can u provide the code for this

Comment: @Haider do you have the same problem as mine?

Comment: @Youssef no, i am using your code with vector data , developing a printing service which output pdf , margins are applied but map is not adjusted accordingly that's why i was asking for the code of referencedEnvelopeToScale method because i think its handled in here