# How to print a map with gridlines and lables with geotools

Tags: java, geotools

I have create a map with geotools but the gridlines i don't know how to lable it.

I saw a similar links [Print a map with Geotools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184359/print-a-map-with-geotools) by @Youssef but did not get the full source code. Here is my code.

**1. Create the Map**

```
private static void generate_map_impge() throws IOException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException,
        SchemaException, org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException, SQLException, JSONException, ParseException {
    // Step 1: Create map
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("World");

    // Step 2: Set projection
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:2136"); // Conic projectionover US
    File files_pdf_shsp = new File(
            "/Users/joh/ONMA_Spatial_Data/boundary.shp");

    int width = 500; // Number of columns
    int height = 500; // Number of rows
    double cellSize = 500; // Size of each grid cell

    SimpleFeatureCollection features = polygons();

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(features.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(features, style);

    ReferencedEnvelope bounds = features.getBounds();
    double delta = bounds.getWidth() / 20.0; // 5% on each side
    bounds.expandBy(delta);

    MapViewport viewport = new MapViewport(bounds);
    map.setViewport(viewport);
    viewport.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs);

    double sideLen = 60;
    ReferencedEnvelope gridBounds = Envelopes.expandToInclude(features.getBounds(), sideLen);

    // Create a feature type
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder tb = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    tb.setName("grid");
    tb.add(
            GridFeatureBuilder.DEFAULT_GEOMETRY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
            Polygon.class,
            gridBounds.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
    tb.add("id", Integer.class);
    SimpleFeatureType TYPE = tb.buildFeatureType();

    // Build the grid the custom feature builder class
    // GridFeatureBuilder builder = new IntersectionBuilder(TYPE, features);
    GridFeatureBuilder builder = new DefaultGridFeatureBuilder();
    SimpleFeatureSource grid = Grids.createSquareGrid(gridBounds, sideLen);

    // Creates the map style
    StyleBuilder styleBuilder = new StyleBuilder();
    PolygonSymbolizer restrictedSymb = styleBuilder.createPolygonSymbolizer(Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, 0);

    // Sets opacity
    restrictedSymb.getFill().setOpacity(styleBuilder.literalExpression(0.1));
    org.geotools.styling.Style myStyle = styleBuilder.createStyle(restrictedSymb);

    Layer layerGrid = new FeatureLayer(grid, myStyle);
    map.addLayer(layerGrid);

    // map.addLayer(grid1);

    // Step 3: Add layers to map
    CoordinateReferenceSystem mapCRS = map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
    map.addLayer(layer);
    // Step 4: Save image
    saveImage(map, "/Users/joh/ONMA_Spatial_Data/graticules.jpg", 1000);
    create_pdf_map(map, "/Users/joh/ONMA_Spatial_Data/graticules.pdf", bounds);

}
```

**2. To genrate the map**

```
static SimpleFeatureCollection polygons() throws SchemaException, org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException {
    // Create SimpleFeatures
    SimpleFeatureType type = DataUtilities.createType("polygons", "id:int,geom:Polygon");
    ListFeatureCollection featureCollection = new ListFeatureCollection(type);
    String[] polygons = {
            "POLYGON((1195655.403 338721.144, 1195605.313 338503.007, 1195413.214 338543.111, 1195470.133 338764.144, 1195655.403 338721.144))"

    };
    WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
    for (int i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
        Geometry polygon = reader.read(polygons[i]);
        featureCollection.add(
                SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(type, new Object[] { i, polygon }, String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    return featureCollection;
}
```

**3. Generate the pdf**

public static String create_pdf_map(final MapContent map, String output_file, ReferencedEnvelope bounds)
throws IOException, SQLException, JSONException, ParseException {

```
    JSONObject request_json = new JSONObject();

    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(output_file));
    // file.;
    try {

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 25, 25);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        document.open();// PDF document opened........
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        BarcodeQRCode barcodeQRCode = new BarcodeQRCode("How are you", 1000, 1000, null);
        Image codeQrImage = barcodeQRCode.getImage();
        codeQrImage.scaleAbsolute(80, 80);
        codeQrImage.setAbsolutePosition(60, 730);
        // codeQrImage.setAbsolutePosition(420, 690);
        document.add(codeQrImage);

        Font font = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN);
        Font font14pt = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 14);
        Font font10pt = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10);

        document.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));

        BaseFont bfaddress = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        PdfContentByte cbaddress = writer.getDirectContent();
        cbaddress.beginText();
        cbaddress.setFontAndSize(bfaddress, 10);

        Date now = new Date();
        // cbaddress.showText("Date: " + now.toGMTString());

        cbaddress.endText();

        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        canvas.moveTo(20, 670);
        canvas.lineTo(700, 670);
        canvas.closePathStroke();

        document.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
        document.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
        document.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
        document.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));

        document.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));

        Font small_bold = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);
        Font small = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);

        document.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));

        Paragraph reportTitle_salutation = new Paragraph("Map: ", new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 11));
        reportTitle_salutation.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(reportTitle_salutation);

        Graphics2D graphics = cb.createGraphics(500, 500);
        Rectangle imageBounds = null;
        imageBounds = new Rectangle(50, 0, 400, 400);
        // call your GTRenderer here
        GTRenderer draw = new StreamingRenderer();
        draw.setMapContent(map);

        draw.paint(graphics, imageBounds, bounds);

        // cleanup
        graphics.dispose();

        document.close();
        file.close();
        return "ok";
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {

        // release resources, if any
        // outputStream.close();
        // response_ws.close();
        // client.close();

    }
    return "ok";

}
```

**4. The result**

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How can I lable the grid and zoom the polygon to the center.

Comment: You need to add labels to `myStyle`

Comment: Can you help with Any Examples